# Writing with C++ functions

Tags: c++

I am trying to write code using multiple functions that simply gets average days employees missed for a company i tried to use global identifiers 
here is my code

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int days;
int numberemployees;
int main()
{
    int days;
    int numberemployees;
    double average;
    cout<<"How many employees do you have";
    cin>>numberemployees;
    daysmissed;
    averagedays;

    return 0;
}

int daysmissed(int)
{
    int days;
    cout<<"How many total days where missed by employees this year";
    cin>>days;
    return days;
}

double averagedays(double)
{
    double average;
    average=days/numberemployees;
    return average;
}
```

Comment: Could you please fix your code indentation. THank you

Comment: What's the question/problem?  State the specific part of your code that is not working, and you'll get better/quicker assistances.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? What results are you getting and what results were you expecting?

Comment: @nietaki Looks like the poster is trying to learn function-calling syntax

Comment: it is saying that there are undeclared identifiers

Comment: You have more problems than just undeclared identifiers. Can I suggest a good C++ book? [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Answer (score 1):

To create a function (other than `int main()`), you need two parts, the declaration and the definition. The declaration is usually at the top of your code and looks like this:

```
int foo(int); //foo(int) declaration
```

The declaration is necessary for code to use the function before it is defined.
The other part of a function is the definition, where you define the function:

```
int foo(int i)
{
     return i + 1;
}
```

Your mistake was you forget the declaration and the messed up the definition

Comment: And messed up the calls.